# Setting the owner of a dialog box in WinForms and C#?

Tags: winforms, dialog

I have an EXE (app.exe) that calls a COM exposed method in a C# DLL (lib.dll). Lib.dll shows a dialog box.

How do I make the dialog box (not a windows message box) recognize the app.exe as the owner, so that when app.exe is minimized, so is the dialog from lib.dll?

The dialog cannot be modal.

Is this a problem that can be solved with Winforms? I prefer a Winforms solution, but will be satisfied with a XAML solution if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your C# Dll is just creating an instance of a form and calling the .Show() method. If that is the case, in your COM exposed method should take an hWnd parameter and set the forms owner to that hWnd.